in dplyr , a question about `na_if(x,y)` when values y equals 0 or 1
in dplyr , na_if can transfer value to NA, but when I want to change 0 or 1 to NA failed . How fix it ?
library(dplyr)
x <- c(1, -1, 0, 10)

this is ok
na_if(x,0)

but below code show Can't recycle y (size 2) to size 4.    I am wondering 0 and c(0,1) are not size 4 , but na_if(x,0) can work.
na_if(x,c(0,1))


Not really a solution, but an explanation as to why this is happening.
na_if does not allow to replace several values with NA
(see also here).
Check the documentation:

y
Value or vector to compare against. When x and y are equal, the
value in x will be replaced with NA.
y is cast to the type of x before comparison.
y is recycled to the size of x before comparison. This means that y
can be a vector with the same size as x, but most of the time this
will be a single value.

Emphasis mine. The second argument has to be either of size 1 or size length(x).

It has to do with the way that na_if() recycles the vector y.
You can achieve your wanted result simply using ifelse() and %in% instead.
x <- c(1, -1, 0, 10)
y <- c(0, 1)

z <- ifelse(x %in% y, NA, x)

z
NA -1 NA 10

